# {"int_err_code":"Authentication Failed","msg":"Wrong grant type"} trying to get access_token and organizer_key in citrix api

Tags: php, api, curl, citrix

I am getting `{"int_err_code":"Authentication Failed","msg":"Wrong grant type"}` trying to get access_token and organizer_key. I use GoToWebinar API. 
Here is my curl:

```
$http_headers=array(
                'Accept:application/json',
                'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );

    $URL = 'https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code'
            .'&code='.$response_key
            .'&client_id='.$consumer_key;

    // send curl post request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why I got this error? I get the right response, executing curl in cmd